# intellisense python

Tags: python, intellisense

Estou aprendendo a programar em *Python* e está ocorrendo, de forma recorrente, a seguinte situação (isso ocorre na IDE *pycharm*, *atom* e *spyder*):

Importei a `matplotlib` da seguinte forma:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Quando digito: `plt.` abre uma janela contendo todos os métodos que eu posso invocar. Então seleciono `plt.axes()`. Se digitar `plt.axes()` nenhuma janela é exibida com os métodos que eu posso chamar.

No livro que estou usando ele executa o comando:

```
plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Não entendo o porque não aparece nenhuma janela exibindo os métodos conforme apresentado acima.

Como resolver tal situação?

Comment: Você sabe qual a versão do python o livro esta utilizando ?

Comment: Isso não é só no Python, as IDEs em geral não dão sugestões ao retorno de uma função, basicamente porque pode acontecer muita coisa numa função e retornar inúmeros valores ou nenhum. O DevTools do chrome não dava sugestões ao retorno de funções, mas recentemente isso mudou, agora quando você escreve no console JS, por exemplo, `document.body.getElementById('el')` e existir esse elemento já tem sugestões como `innerHTML`, `value`, etc

Comment: Removi a minha resposta, já que interpretei a pergunta erroneamente.

Comment: Ele usa a versão 3 do python. Então pelo que eu entendi é normal esse comportamento da IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Python é uma linguagem dinâmica, portanto, não é possível saber de antemão quais métodos podem ser invocados em um objeto, sem executar o código. O que a maioria das IDEs fazem é uma análise estática dos objetos, retornando métodos associados ao seu "tipo inferido", porém, no caso de respostas dinâmicas de funções, atributos dinâmicos e classes com `__getattr__` definido isso é muito difícil ou impossível de fazer sem executar o código. Pode até retornar resultados inválidos.

A solução é ignorar o que o editor está completando e escrever o código na raça - Use o recurso de completar código da IDE para te ajudar a escrever nomes longos, mas não dependa dele para listar os métodos disponíveis; Para isso use a documentação.

Pra ilustrar segue um exemplo de código dinâmico: Uma classe é definida com um método chamado `metodo_nao_existe` porém logo depois esse método é removido da classe. A sua IDE provavelmente vai se confundir:

```
class Teste:
    def metodo_nao_existe(self):
        print("Eu nao existo")

def _metodo(self):
    print("Eu existo")

del Teste.metodo_nao_existe
Teste.metodo_existe = _metodo

t = Teste()
t.metodo_existe()
```